# IIS7 - HTTP 502 in IE8 over HTTPS

Tags: iis-7, https, internet-explorer-8, 502-error

I am developing web app using .NET 4.0
I'ts hosted on IIS7 and served over HTTPS.

When I try to request a page with IE8, it doesn't load completely. So I looked into fiddler, and it shows me an HTTP 502 Error for js file included in the page... It works fine in Mozilla though.

I am getting this error randomly, sometimes everything works smoothly.

To give you a general idea of the environment:
Web server behind a load balancer.

I am requesting the page (simple HTML with some JavaScript) over HTTPS.

any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

502 means Bad Gateway. It's typically something a Load Balancer (or any reverse proxy) says to you when the target of the upstream request doesn't respond to it, or says something nasty.

Look at the request, look at the Server web logs (and HTTPERR logs) and the LB logs for the time of the request, and try to match them up.